# Ternary Conditional Control

Tags: c

I have a question regarding Ternary Conditional in C. How can I do this if-else statement in Ternary Conditional?

```
if (argc <= 1) {
        printf("Something");
        printf("Something");
        func(NULL);
    } else {
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
            fun2(argv[i]);
        }
}
```

Comment: You can't really. Why would you?

Comment: Just I would like to know if it is possible. I am not sure if it is possible this why I asked.

Comment: @Rawad Bader You can not substitute a for loop for an expression.

Comment: You could put the loop in a function, then call the function from the ternary.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Oh, I see. Do you know what is the reason for that?

Comment: Because loops are statements, not expressions.

Comment: @Barmar I am sorry but can you give me an example of how that can be done. Thank you.

Comment: @RawadBader Loops are not expressions-statements. If you want to use a loop you need to enclose it in a function.

Comment: Write 2-fucntions containing the code from the body of the `if` and `else` and then call the functions with a ternary.

Answer (score 3):

Since the parameters of the ternary are expressions, and loops are not expressions, you can't put the printing loop directly in the ternary.

But a function call is an expression, so you can put a call to a function that prints the arguments into the ternary.

```
int print_args(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        fun2(argv[i]);
    }
}

argc <= 1 ? 
    (printf("Something"), printf("Something"), func(NULL)) :
    print_args(argc, argv);
```

Comment: You can using GCC extension: https://ideone.com/Wob13i

Comment: Yes, but it's not portable, so I'm not going to advocate it. Feel free to post an answer that shows how to do it.

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it with standard C, as noted in the other answer. But there are some compiler extensions that can make it possible. `GCC` has a ["Statement-expression" extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs) that allows a braces-enclosed block to return a value as an expression, which makes it possible to use it in the conditional construct. So your example is conversion is almost straight-forward:

```
 (argc <= 1) ? ({
    printf("Something");
    printf("Something");
    func(NULL);
 }) : ({
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        fun2(argv[i]);
    }});
```

Or for those who want a fully compilable example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(void *p) {}
void fun2(void *p) {}

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
     (argc <= 1) ? ({
        printf("Something");
        printf("Something");
        func(NULL);
     }) : ({
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
            fun2(argv[i]);
        }});
    return 0;
}
```

NOTE: The fact you *can* do it does not mean you *should*. Ternary conditionals are tending to be less readable than your conventional `if/else` statements, and overcomplicating them do not help it at all.

Comment: Should have checked your answer before writing the comment...

Comment: Nice, thank you for the help.